# Angled brush in Paint.NET

Tags: paint.net

Does anyone know how I can use an angled paint brush on Paint.NET? Like the one in Microsoft's Paint (XP/Vista versions).

I want to use it for calligraphy:

[image]

Here's a close up of what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [CustomBrushesMini](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/14845-custombrushesmini-v19/page__hl__custombrushesmini) inadequate, so I opened up GIMP, and saw that there were a few calligraphy brushes. I could even set the angle for my brush! It was good, but then I did some research, and found that Inkscape has a built in Calligraphy "brush". You can control many things about it, and it looks promising.

From now on, I'll use GIMP for Custom Brushes, Inkscape for calligraphy, and Paint.NET for other (which is actually more time than the other two Image Editors combined).

Answer (score 3):

It's a tremendous kluge, but you can try the [CustomBrushesMini](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/14845-custombrushesmini-v19/page__hl__custombrushesmini) plugin.